# How to write constraint for a transaction class in which I need only 50% packets to be randomized?

Tags: constraints, system-verilog, uvm

I need to write a transaction class such that each packet has a random SA[7:0] field, DA[7:0] field & a DATA field.
The length of the data is random between 1 byte to 64 bytes. The content of the DATA field can be random (or) some other fixed pattern.50% of packets to have random data in all bytes of data. 25% of packets to have 8’h55 in all bytes of data. 25% of packets to have 8’hAA in all bytes of data

```
  class my_transaction extends uvm_sequence_item;
  'uvm_object_utils(my_transaction);

  function new(string name="my_transaction")
  super.new(name);
  endfunction

  rand bit[7:0] SA;
  rand bit[7:0] DA;
  rand bit[7:0] data[];

  constraint my_c { data.size() inside [1:64] };
  ????how to write constraint for dynamic array data[] here ??

  endclass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are your friend:

i) a *control knob*. A control knob is a variable that gets randomised in order to control the randomisation process. So, let's randomise a variable to decide whether we want the `data` array to be random, 55 or AA.

```
typedef enum {RANDOM, FIVE_FIVE, A_A} control_knob_t;
rand control_knob_t control_knob;

constraint dist_constraint { control_knob dist {RANDOM := 2, FIVE_FIVE := 1, A_A := 1}; }
```

ii) `post_randomize` method. This is SystemVerilog, not UVM. `post_randomize` is called after the randomisation of the class has taken place and allows you to do things once randomisation has occurred. In this case, we'll let the standard randomisation randomise the length of the `data` array and then we'll fill in the values of `data` in the `post_randomize` method.

```
function void post_randomize;
  case (control_knob)
    RANDOM:    foreach (data[i]) 
                 data[i] = $urandom_range(0,255);
    FIVE_FIVE: foreach (data[i]) 
                 data[i] = 8'h55;
    A_A:       foreach (data[i]) 
                 data[i] = 8'haa;
  endcase
endfunction
```

---

[MCVE] :

```
module M;

  class C;

    rand bit[7:0] data[];

    typedef enum {RANDOM, FIVE_FIVE, A_A} control_knob_t;
    rand control_knob_t control_knob;

    constraint my_c { data.size() inside {[1:4]}; }

    constraint dist_constraint { control_knob dist {RANDOM := 2, FIVE_FIVE := 1, A_A := 1}; }

    function void post_randomize;
      case (control_knob)
        RANDOM:    foreach (data[i]) 
                     data[i] = $urandom_range(0,255);
        FIVE_FIVE: foreach (data[i]) 
                     data[i] = 8'h55;
        A_A:       foreach (data[i]) 
                     data[i] = 8'haa;
      endcase
    endfunction

  endclass

  C c;

  initial
    begin
      c = new;
      repeat (100)
        begin
          c.randomize;
          $display("c = %p", c);
        end
    end

 endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2cPk

Comment: Hi Mathew, thanks for replying. I tried to run this code with no. of packets changed to 8(repeat(8)), I should expect 4 packets with control knob RAND, 2 packets with FIVE_FIVE and 2 with A_A, but somehow it generates only one packet with control knob RAND .

Comment: You wouldn't expect _exactly_ 25%/25%/50% in such a small sample. It's random. If you rolled a dice six times, you wouldn't expect exactly one of each number, would you.

Answer (score 2):

I was working on a similar approach to Matthew's, but I prefer not to use post_randomize for randomization if easily avoided

```
module top;
  class A;
    rand bit[7:0] data[];      
    typedef enum {RAND, h55, hAA} knob_t;
    rand knob_t knobs[];

    constraint size_c { data.size() inside {[1:64]}; data.size == knobs.size; }

    constraint dist_c { 
      foreach(knobs[i]) knobs[i] dist {RAND := 50, h55 := 25, hAA := 25}; }
    constraint data_element_c {
      foreach (data[i]) {
        knobs[i] == h55 -> data[i] == 8'h55;
        knobs[i] == hAA -> data[i] == 8'hAA;
      } }
  endclass

  A a = new;

  initial
      repeat (10)
        begin
          assert(a.randomize);
          $display("%p", a);
        end

 endmodule
```